Proving the inequality from a problem on Diophantine approximation
In the book Diophantine Approximations and Diophantine Equations” by W.M.Schmidt, the following is Exercise $1$b in chapter $2$ (page $38$):
Given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N>0$, there exist $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$, not both $0$ , with
$N|\alpha y-x|+N^{-1}|y| \leqq \sqrt{2} .$
Now use the arithmetic-geometric inequality to show that given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\mathbb{Q}$, there are infinitely many rationals $\frac{x}{y}$ with
$$
\left|\alpha-\frac{x}{y}\right|<\frac{1}{2 y^2}.
$$

Dividing the above equation by $|y|$ and using the AM-GM inequality yields the result.
However, I am interested in how to find the given inequality in the problem. Using Dirichlet's theorem I can show that the L.H.S. is $ \leq2,$ but how do I show that it is less than $\sqrt2?$

Meta-comment: of course you can find the original inequality with a worse right-hand side using Dirichlet's theorem; that's the very point of the exercise, as indicated by the parenthetical comment at the end.

If $N\le \sqrt{2}$, let $x=1,y=0$. Now suppose $N>\sqrt{2}$.
Let $F_n$ be the $n$-th Farey sequence, consisting of $\frac{0}{1}$ and all $\frac{s}{t}$ such that $s\le t\le n,(s,t)=1$, ordered from lowest to the highest. For examples see Wikipedia.
Suppose there’s an irrational $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ that doesn’t satisfy the condition in the question. We may suppose $\alpha\in [0,1]$.
Lemma. $\alpha$ can’t be in $[\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}]$, where $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}$ are neighbor terms in a Farey sequence $F_n$ that $n\le\sqrt{2} N$ and $(\sqrt{2}b-N)(\sqrt{2}d-N)\le 0$.
Proof. Suppose $\alpha$ in such $[\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}]$. By simple computation we have:
$$
\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{b}-\frac{1}{N}}{N} + \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{d}-\frac{1}{N}}{N} \ge \frac{1}{bd}
$$
(The inequality above is equivalent to $(\sqrt{2}b-N)(\sqrt{2}d-N)\le 0$.) By the property of Farey sequence, $\frac{c}{d}-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{bd}$. So we get two cases:
Case 1. $\alpha-\frac{a}{b}\le\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{b}-\frac{1}{N}}{N}$.
That is $N |b\alpha -a|+N^{-1}|b|\le \sqrt{2}$, contradicting our assumptions about $\alpha$.
Case 2. $\frac{c}{d}-\alpha\le\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{d}-\frac{1}{N}}{N}$.
That is $N |d\alpha -c|+N^{-1}|d|\le\sqrt{2}$, contradicting our assumptions about $\alpha$. The lemma is proved.
Now we continue the proof of the original problem. For every $1\le n\le \sqrt{2} N$, let $\alpha$ lie in $(\frac{a_n}{b_n},\frac{c_n}{d_n})$ that $\frac{a_n}{b_n},\frac{c_n}{d_n}$ are neighbor terms in the Farey sequence $F_n$.  We observe that:

For every $n>1$, $b_n \ne d_n$.
When $n=1$, both $b_n,d_n$ are smaller than $\frac{N}{\sqrt{2}}$. When $n=\lfloor \sqrt{2} N \rfloor$, $b_n,d_n$ can’t both be smaller than $\frac{N}{\sqrt{2}}$. (Note that $\frac{a_n+c_n}{b_n+d_n}$ is also in the Farey sequence)
If $b_n\ne n$ then $b_{n-1}=b_n$. If $d_n\ne n$ then $d_{n-1}=d_n$.

Let $n$ go to $1$ from $\lfloor \sqrt{2} N \rfloor$. By the observations above, there exists at least one $n$ that exactly one of $b_n,d_n$ is smaller than $\frac{N}{\sqrt{2}}$. The lemma leads to a contradiction.
